# Not able to install my ARKit supported app in iPhone 6, but demo app by apple is running successfully on same iphone

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, arkit

When I try to install ARKit supported app in iPhone 6 its saying **requires the “arkit” capability which is not supported by your's iPhone** but then how the demo app of ARKit provided by apple is running on the same iPhone.

Comment: check your deployment target

Comment: It's 11.0, but it's also 11.0 for the Apple's demo app

Comment: Had a similar issue. No idea why 6 isn't included in the SDK minimum but the demo is, but thats just the way things are.

Comment: Accept the answer you are given.

Comment: Read the question and answer once.
None of the answers clarifies the question asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar question, although the purpose was different. I hope this answer helps someone:

If you have an iPhone that came out before the iPhone 6S it will not work. However, you can have an app that has ARKit if you remove `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` from the plist. This way you are able to run (although you will not see anything). This allows you to have an app that has ARKit as a bonus (and only enable/disable a button if ARKit can be used)

Answer (score 5):

at WWDC 2017, Apple officially announced that minimum device required for ARKit to work is iPhone 6S

Comment: yeah that I know, but I am wondering how their demo app works in iPhone 6

Comment: yeah, this is what i said :), accept my answer yar 

Comment: @SamehSalama Read my question again, what I am saying is I am able to install the demo app of apple in iPhone 6 but if I create my own AR project it doesn't install on the phone. And I know apple has declared at WWDC that AR works above iPhone6, That's why I have asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

These are **ARKit** supported **iPhone** models. ARKit designed for iPhones and iPad that use the A9, A10 & A11 Processors.

1. iPhone 6s
2. iPhone 6s Plus
3. iPhone SE
4. iPad(2017)
5. iPhone 7
6. iPhone 7 Plus
7. iPhone 8
8. iPhone 8 Plus
9. iPhone X

Answer (score 0):

For **ARKit 3**

> People Occlusion and the use of motion capture, simultaneous front and back camera, and multiple face tracking are supported on devices with A12/A12X Bionic chips, ANE, and TrueDepth Camera.

It means ARKit 3 new features will be supported by iPhone XR and greater models.