# Normal app with ARKit as a "bonus"?

Tags: ios, iphone, arkit

I am doing some experiments with ARKit and tried to run in an iPhone 5S just to see what happens:

I got this error in Xcode 9.0 beta 6:

> “ARDemo” requires the “ARKit” capability which is not supported by iPhone

So far so good. My question is (and is kinda related with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45528366/not-able-to-install-my-arkit-supported-app-in-iphone-6-but-demo-app-by-apple-is)): is it possible to install in an iPhone lower that iPhone 6S even though the ARKit will not work?

I want to be able to offer ARKit as a complement to an app, but only offer it if the device supports it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ship a product that uses ARKit to any device, provided you check for it runtime. If the package won't install to devices then the project has the arkit capability marked as required and this will block installation. Just remove this from the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` section in the info.plist and the installation will succeed.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit?language=objc)

Comment: Didn't know about that section! Thanks a lot! :)